# Why: Non-void function should return a value

Tags: ios, swift

So I am having an issue where the following is now throwing an error Non-void function should return a value

```
 func newsfetch() -> [News]{
    var tempNews: [News] = []
                let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news"
                guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return } // ERROR: Non-void function should return a value

                  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err)
                      in

                      guard let news = data else { return }

                      do{
                        let newsdata = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: news)
                        print(newsdata.news)
                        newsdata.news.forEach(){
                          //  print($0.title)

                            tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title))
                        }


                        }catch let jsonErr{

                            print("error json ", jsonErr)
                        }


                  }.resume()

    return tempNews

      }
```

I am unsure why this has happened as I took the JSON feed script from our now playing function and it works like a charm.

the only difference is @obj is not at the front of this func because it causes an error with the -> [news] command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change return to return(tempNews)
Because you are returning null where a type of [News] expected

Proper statement

else { return tempNews}

Comment: thx that worked but now the tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title)) is not working

Comment: I don't get any error just a blank table - I'll make it another question.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful and try printing out the contents before appending so that you know objects are there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081928/appending-is-not-firing-json-swift

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return` it means exit the function without doing anything. Obviousely your function needs to return `[News]`.
There are two way to fix it:

```
guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return [News]()}
```

or make your function:

```
func newsfetch() -> [News]?
```

The later needs special care when you call that function. You most probably need optional chaining or force unwrapping(Not recommended)